# Collection of intersections of a collection: name?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a standard name or notation for the collection of all sets that are intersections of sets in a collection $C$? I am talking about
$\{\bigcap S : S\subset C\}$.
Assume $C$ is finite, if needed.

Comment: I’ve seen $C^\cap$ used.

Comment: Interesting - is that standard?

Comment: Not standard I’d say. But probably understandable to most.

Comment: I’ve not seen $C^\cap$ used, and I don’t consider it standard, but it’s a reasonable choice — **provided** that the writer defined it before using it. I don’t think that there is a standard notation.